# Drawing text in core graphics

Tags: xcode5, core-graphics, objective-c++

What is a simple way of drawing text using core graphics? I tried CGContextShowTextAtPoint but it doesn't work.

```
const char s[6]="hello";           
CGContextShowTextAtPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 50, 50, s, 5);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, `CGContextShowTextAtPoint` is deprecated in iOS 7. So thats the reason your code is not working.

But there are many alternatives to it. I think `[NSString drawAtPoint:aPoint withAttributes:dictOfAttributes]` is what you are looking for.

Further, you can refer to these docs for support according to your needs:

[https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSString_AppKitAdditions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/drawAtPoint:withAttributes](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSString_AppKitAdditions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/drawAtPoint%3awithAttributes):

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/CustomTextProcessing/CustomTextProcessing.html